# automatically download latest stable tarball from sourceforge from command line?

Tags: command-line, opensource-projects

I'd like to install a program from sourceforge sources. Is there a way to download the latest stable source from SourceForge? an example for `ntopng` would be very welcome.

Comment: as the link to latest ource is `http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntop/files/latest/download?source=files` Do you try `wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntop/files/latest/download?source=files` ?

Comment: @Kiwy ah thanks, I didn't realise wget was able to download a file via a link like that. i've always done it with direct links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can use `wget` and SourceForge, always use the url for the latest source.

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/$$PROJECT_URL$$/files/latest/download?source=files
```

Where `$$PROJECT_URL$$` needs to be replace by the part of url corresponding to the project.
for `ntopng` ==> `ntop` which gives you:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntop/files/latest/download?source=files
```